# php code to check IP address and stop script

Tags: php

I need simple code to check server IP address and if was not equal xx.xx.xx.xx , then php script stop and not work. This way I want limit this script to work for specific IP only.

Comment: Do you pay enough?

Comment: `<?
            $allowed_ip =$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //not reliable
            if($allowed_ip != XX.XX.XX.XX){
                exit('Forbidden');
            }`

Comment: @Kisaragi  They are asking about the server's IP, not the visitor's.

Comment: I see there wasn't much effort put into this question. I'll bet you'd spend hours on Google trying to find something else though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who tried to help.

> $ip = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
>
> $serverip = str_replace("\n","",shell_exec("ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet
>   addr' | awk -F':' {'print $2'} | awk -F' ' {'print $1'}")); if
>   ($serverip != $ip) {die('WRONG SERVER IP');}

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.. If the server serving the page is not at IP 100.100.100.100 exit the script.

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] !='100.100.100.100') {die('WRONG SERVER IP');} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I just got this error : PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_ADDR in